# Android MediaPlayer - how load load multiple files from raw folder

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I was looking at this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm) of MediaPlayer, and I wanted to find out, how to load multiple files mp3 from the raw folder and make all them play in a loop.

I really wanted to load 4 short mp3 files from the raw folder, so when play bt activated. all audio will play in a loop. Thanks

```
package com.example.mediaplayer;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   public TextView songName,startTimeField,endTimeField;
   private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
   private double startTime = 0;
   private double finalTime = 0;
   private Handler myHandler = new Handler();;
   private int forwardTime = 5000; 
   private int backwardTime = 5000;
   private SeekBar seekbar;
   private ImageButton playButton,pauseButton;
   public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      songName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
      startTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      endTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
      playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
      pauseButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
      songName.setText("song.mp3");
      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
      seekbar.setClickable(false);
      pauseButton.setEnabled(false);

   }

   public void play(View view){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing sound", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mediaPlayer.start();
      finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
      startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
      if(oneTimeOnly == 0){
         seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
         oneTimeOnly = 1;
      } 

      endTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) - 
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) finalTime)))
      );
      startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) startTime)))
      );
      seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
      myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);
      pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
      playButton.setEnabled(false);
   }

   private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
         startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
            toMinutes((long) startTime)))
         );
         seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
         myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
      }
   };
   public void pause(View view){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pausing sound", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      mediaPlayer.pause();
      pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
      playButton.setEnabled(true);
   }    
   public void forward(View view){
      int temp = (int)startTime;
      if((temp+forwardTime)<=finalTime){
         startTime = startTime + forwardTime;
         mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
      }
      else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "Cannot jump forward 5 seconds", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

   }
   public void rewind(View view){
      int temp = (int)startTime;
      if((temp-backwardTime)>0){
         startTime = startTime - backwardTime;
         mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
      }
      else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "Cannot jump backward 5 seconds",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the resource id of the all the audio files in your raw folder using following code

```
ArrayList<Integer> audioResourceId=new ArrayList<Integer>();
public void listRaw(){
    Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
        int resourceID=fields[count].getInt(fields[count]);//resource id
        audioResourceId.add(resourceID);
    }
}
```

Than implement MediaPlayer.onCompletionListener

```
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(index<audioResourceId.size())
            index++;
        else
            index=0;
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,audioResourceId(index));
    mediaPlayer.start();

    }
```